# How to set the content or iframe source in created custom page tabs using graph API in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I get how to create a custom tab using graph API from the official documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs. But I didn't get how can we integrate our website into the iframes to display our page into the created custom page tab.

Comment: You need to add the Page Tab platform in your basic settings in the app dashboard, and then you specify the entry URL there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply **:)**. But I have so many users and each user has different secure page tab URL can't we send the URL through API from our end.

Comment: No, that is not how this works. You can only have one page tab URL configured per app. If you need to know which FB page your tab was embedded on, then you need to get that info from the `signed_request` parameter that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#authorization-and-customization

Comment: But how can we do that for user1 I need to embed user1.***.com and for user2 I need to embed user2.***.com? Can't we achieve that?

Comment: You can _redirect_ to those specific URLs, _after_ you have checked what page id you are on.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you provide me with some reference on how to do that?

Comment: What specifically? How to decode the signed request? See linked documentation page.